# how to create a folder on remote machine c#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a folder on remote machine using remote machine administrator credentials, using Directory.CreateDirectory how to pass user name and password for creating directory.

Comment: Do you have access to the remote machine? As in can you do remote login?

Comment: As @PratikGaikwad suggest, first you need to know if have access to that folder, and if you are granted to write into it.

Comment: If you have remote access then you have to look take a look at [ConnectionOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) class

Comment: @PratikGaikwad, yes I m able to remote login to machine, I have the admin user name and password.

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca, since I m creating a new folder in c- drive, I think permission is not required

Answer (score 1):

First check if you have access to the folder and if are allowed to write.
If you have, then use this way:

```
var directorypath = @"\\172.16.136.35\SharedFolder1\";
(!Directory.Exists(directorypath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directorypath);
}
```

Where "172.16.136.35" must be replaced by the remote computer ip or dns.
Take a look at this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0df91307-f6dd-4728-a55b-7d25ae1c5bef/createdirectory-on-remote-machine?forum=csharplanguage)

Now, if what you want is executing as admin, you might declare it in the manifest, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator)

The code below was published in the same post and lets you check if you are running as admin or you dont.

```
using System.Security.Principal;
public bool IsUserAdministrator()
{
    bool isAdmin;
    try
    {
        WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(user);
        isAdmin = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        isAdmin = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        isAdmin = false;
    }
    return isAdmin;
}
```

Really, I dont know whether is a programmatic way to force an application to elevate its own perms. In my experience, the app should be elevated at begining.
Lets take an example:

- **command prompt**: many times we find programs, process, or whatever, which needs to be installed as Admin, if I opened cmd as a common user, usually it throws an exception. Then you have to close cmd and open it again as admin, right?

I could think in many security risks if I was some Operating System and I allowed to anyone to elevate itself as admin.

I hope you to solve the problem.

Comment: I want to use admin credentials for creating folder here.

Comment: I've edited the answer in order to help you to understand the way i think it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access on remote machine then you can use tcp/ip protocol to create the folder directly using below code:

```
string _directoryName = @"\\ServerIP\C$\FolderName";
(!Directory.Exists(_directoryName))
{   
    Directory.CreateDirectory(_directoryName);
}
```

however if you want to create the folder using admin user only with specific permission you can use `psexec` to create the folder. I am assuming you know how to invoke external exe or process from c#. You can pass below command argument to `psexec` for creating the folder

```
psexec \\\IPAddress -u username -p Password cmd /c mkdir c:\FolderName
```

Comment: where are you actually pointing to the psexec.exe your post assumes that the file is installed locally, but what if I want to run it with it stored in a applications Resource folder..?